# bitnami/rabbitmq docker compose: plain login refused

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq, bitnami

I failed to connect to the RabbitMQ server (use bitnami/rabbitmq:3.11 image) from my own custom python app with error `user 'admin' can only connect via localhost`

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.9"

x-logging: &default-logging
  driver: journald

services:
  python_app_example:
    image: python_app
    logging: *default-logging
    expose:
      - "32000"
    environment:
      - MINERS_RABBITMQ_URL=amqp://${RABBITMQ_USERNAME}:${RABBITMQ_PASSWORD}@${RABBITMQ_HOST}:${RABBITMQ_PORT}//
    command: python3 -m python_app.app
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "nc", "-z", "-v", "localhost", "32000"]
      interval: 3s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 50
    depends_on:
      rabbitmq:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - rabbitmq

  rabbitmq:
    image: bitnami/rabbitmq:3.11
    logging: *default-logging
    ports:
      - "29998:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_HOST=rabbitmq
      - RABBITMQ_USERNAME
      - RABBITMQ_PASSWORD
      - RABBITMQ_PLUGINS=rabbitmq_management
      - RABBITMQ_SECURE_PASSWORD=yes
      - RABBITMQ_LOGS=-
    volumes:
      - 'rabbitmq_data:/bitnami/rabbitmq/mnesia'
    healthcheck:
      test: rabbitmq-diagnostics -q ping
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 10
    networks:
      - rabbitmq

networks:
  miners_server:
  rabbitmq:

volumes:
  rabbitmq_data:
    driver: local
```

my .env file:

```
RABBITMQ_HOST=rabbitmq
RABBITMQ_PORT=5672
RABBITMQ_USERNAME=admin
RABBITMQ_PASSWORD=admin
```

python_app_example failed with error:
`Connection to amqp://admin:******@rabbitmq:5672// closed.  ... ProbableAuthenticationError: ('ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.',)`

Here are rabbitmq logs `docker logs rabbitmq-1`:
 `2023-12-11 17:06:03.755693+00:00 [info] <0.2916.0> accepting AMQP connection <0.2916.0> (172.28.0.3:44366 -> 172.28.0.2:5672) 2023-12-11 17:06:03.756757+00:00 [error] <0.2916.0> Error on AMQP connection <0.2916.0> (172.28.0.3:44366 -> 172.28.0.2:5672, state: starting): 2023-12-11 17:06:03.756757+00:00 [error] <0.2916.0> PLAIN login refused: user 'admin' can only connect via localhost 2023-12-11 17:06:03.756857+00:00 [info] <0.2916.0> closing AMQP connection <0.2916.0> (172.28.0.3:44366 -> 172.28.0.2:5672)`

What should i change in my docker compose file to allow connection from a remote machine for admin user?

After executed `docker compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d` i tried to connect to rabbitmsq container and do the following:

```
$ docker exec -it rabbitmq-1 bash

$ rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / admin ".*" ".*" ".*"
```

It didn't work for some reason, but anyway it seems like a bad way to handle the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html#loopback-users) :

> By default, the `guest` user is prohibited from connecting from remote hosts. It can only connect over a loopback interface (i.e. `localhost`).

The Bitnami RabbitMQ image implements the same kind of mechanism for its default user. If you go into your container and get the content of the configuration file located at `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf`, you will see these lines :

```
default_user = admin
default_pass = admin
...
loopback_users.admin = true
```

This prevents you from logging into the `admin` user without connecting over `localhost`.

You have two options there :

- Use the [official RabbitMQ image](https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq) which doesn't have this kind of restriction.
- Rewrite the configuration directly in the container by creating your custom image from the Bitnami image.

I would also remove the `RABBITMQ_USERNAME` and `RABBITMQ_PASSWORD` environment variables of the `rabbitmq` service they're already defined in your `.env` file, and `RABBITMQ_HOST` which is not supported by the image.